# Why was Lucius Fox still a part of Wayne Enterprises in Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises, the-dark-knight

At the end of [The Dark Knight](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/) Fox told Batman that spying on people wasn't part of his job description. And then he asked Batman to consider this his resignation. Batman said "When you are done type in your name".

Yet in [The Dark Knight Rises](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1345836/?ref_=tt_rec_tt) we see Fox as part of Wayne Enterprises as usual. Why? What happened? Is this just a mistake?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe the phrasing was that "while this machine is at Wayne Enterprises I won't be".  In the scene you're referring to he typed in his name to delete the software and destroy the machine.

The machine is no longer there so Lucius Fox was happy to remain.

Comment: That's why he walks away smiling as the machine starts to explode.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of The Dark Knight, Batman says "Sometimes people deserve to have their faith rewarded" and at that very scene Lucius types in his name which destroys that machine. So he appears in TDKR.